# Filter Count by conditions

Tags: ms-access

I have a table with a start and end date for each record, and a duration between the two that I have calculated. I now need to group these durations by intervals (1-29, 30-59, etc) and count how many durations fall in each category, displayed in a form/report. How should I both count the number of durations as well as filter them by size?

Answer (score 1):

Construct a field with calculation that assigns an identifier for the interval groupings.

`Switch([Duration]<30,1, [Duration]<60,2, [Duration]<90,3, True,4)`

Or try the Partition() function. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Partition-Function-1A846A33-60C7-4371-8E77-C94278274DC5?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Use Report Sorting & Grouping features and do the summary aggregate calcs in textboxes on report.

Comment: Where would I enter this? As an expression in the query or in the form/report itself?

Comment: Can be done in query or as expression in textbox and in report Grouping criteria. Try it in report. Then it will be easy to reference the constructed field in the report Grouping criteria.

Comment: Correction, I meant try it in query then it will be a field that can be referenced in report.